# Adding up all the positive numbers in Excel

Tags: excel, sum, openoffice.org, worksheet-function

Is there a way to add up all of the positive numbers in a row/column but ignoring all of the negative numbers?  Like SUM(), except that it ignores negative numbers.  Would I have to use VBA?  If so, how would I do it in VBA?

If it can't be done in Excel, can it be done in OpenOffice Calc?

Comment: A quick Google would have got this for you ;)

Comment: Dang, I got smoked by 5 answers in less than a minute

Comment: Yeah i missed it by 3 seconds.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use SUMIF.  YTo sum all the positive numbers in Column A:

```
=SUMIF(A:A,">0")
```

Same function exists in Excel and Calc

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUMIF(A1:A99,">0")
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure like this:

```
=SUMIF(B1:B50,">0")
```

This will add all positive numbers in cells B1 to B50.

Answer (score 0):

=SUMIF(A1:A4,">=0")

Answer (score 0):

SUMIF() will do the trick:

```
 =SUMIF(A1:A100,">0")
```

You could also use an array formula, but that's more complicated and has no benefit over SUMIF()

Answer (score 0):

Get auxiliary row/colums, in another tab if necessary them fill them with =if(A5>0;A5;0). That will turn negatives to zero. Then sum those.

Answer (score -2):

I am an excel noob...and after an hour or so of wondering what I am doing wrong and why wont it work for me, I realize how important each symbol is.  this formula should have a semicolon instead of comma.  Once I changed that the formula didn't give me any errors
=sumif(A:A;">0")
hope this helps