# Find Some in Excel by omitting negative figures

Tags: excel

How do I find the sum of only positive values in a column in Excel?

For example, if a column contains 12,85,100,0,55,-45,-80,200 sum this columns by omitting negative figures would be 452.00?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding up all the positive numbers in Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596745/adding-up-all-the-positive-numbers-in-excel)

Answer (score 0):

Use the array formula:

```
=SUM(IF(A1:A100>0,A1:A100))
```

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Answer (score 0):

`=SUMIF(A1:A100;">=0")`

That's the quickest way

Another useful way if you are working on an single column of data is to just use the name of the column instead of a range:

```
=SUMIF(B:B;">=0")
```